# passing array value from javascript to php using form

Tags: javascript, php

creating form using javascript

```
    var mapForm = document.createElement("form");
    mapForm.method = "POST";
    mapForm.action = "/Application/index.php/ApplicationController/request";   
    var dataArray = {name: "first", lastName: "second"};
    var mapInput = document.createElement("input");
    mapInput.type = "hidden";
    mapInput.name = "data[]";
    mapInput.id = "data[]";
    mapInput.value =dataArray;
    mapForm.appendChild(mapInput);    
    document.body.appendChild(mapForm);
    mapForm.submit();
```

here is my code to retrieve form data

```
 if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
 $result_array=$_POST['data'];
 echo 'Data'.$result_array['name'];
```

but it shows

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: name
```

how to solve this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
mapInput.name = "name";
```

instead

```
mapInput.name = "data[]";
```